# Make a button that takes you to a random next page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So I'm trying to make a quiz app with `Django`. So far I've got a `SQL` database that can autopopulate a template given a question id. If I go to `http://localhost:8000/polls/2/` it'll give me the second quiz question.

I'm trying to make a button that'll take me to a random quiz question when clicked on.

Inside I have the following methods:

```
# myproject/polls/view.py

def get_question_page(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(id=question_id)
    except Exception as e:
        question = None
    context = {'question': question}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def get_random_page(request):
    n = Question.objects.count()
    rand = random.randint(1, n)
    return get_question_page(request, rand)
```

And the following urls:

```
# myproject/polls/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_question_page, name='question'),
    url(r'^rand/$', views.get_random_page, name='rand'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/select/$', views.select, name='select'),
]
```

I've attempted using the following code inside `myproject/polls/index.html`:

```
<!-- myproject/polls/index.html -->

<form action="{% url 'views.get_random_page' %}" method="POST">
    <input id="submit"a type="button" value="Click" />
</form>
```

But I only end up with:

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/2/
Reverse for 'views.get_random_page' not found.
'views.get_random_page' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`
```

Can someone explain what's going wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: where are your URLs patterns? please add them

Comment: @Lemayzeur done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add app_name to your urls.py

```
app_name = 'your_app_name'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_question_page, name='question'),
url(r'^rand/$', views.get_random_page, name='rand'),
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/select/$', views.select, name='select'),
]
```

Add url in the format below and change input type to submit to submit the form.

```
<form action="{% url 'your_app_name:rand' %}" method="POST">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
```

Comment: the error message stopped, so the page is finally rendering. but nothing happens now when i click the button

Comment: @wheeeee Change the input type to submit to submit the form

Comment: So some sort of redirect seems to be working, but now whenever I click the button, I get: `Reverse for 'get_question_page' not found. 'get_question_page' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: @wheeeee remove the `return get_question_page(request, rand)` from your `get_random_page` function and just call `get_question_page(request, rand)` at the end of  `get_random_page` function

Comment: the line `return get_question_page(request, question_id=rand)` worked. before i was using `return redirect("get_question_page",question_id=rand)` as suggested by a previous user

Answer (score 0):

What this view `get_random_page()` returns is not not correct, your should have [`redirect('url_name')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) which returns an `HttpResponseRedirect` to the appropriate URL for the arguments passed or directly with [`HttpResponseRedirect('url_path')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

instead of this:

```
return get_question_page(request, rand)
```

try:

```
return redirect(get_question_page,question_id=rand)
# without quotes means, you call directly the function
# so the function should be above in order for python to find it.

return redirect("get_question_page",question_id=rand)
# With quotes, you actually call the url_name
# this is better, when you have to call views from other apps
```

Comment: it's still not working. inspecting page source shows `<form action="/polls/rand/" method="POST">`

Comment: you should use it like I said, as Django suggested, did you add the `{% csrf_token %}` inside your form? in question, I see that you missed it